Why does VS Code sometimes colorise python print() as a magic method?
I didn't like VS Codes existing colour scheme for syntax highlighting in python, so I added rules using the textmate scopes. For functions, I used "entity.name.function.python". However, sometimes, when printing a string, print is colorised the correct colour (e.g. green). However, when printing a class, it colorised print() different color. The textmate scope now says "support.function.builtin.python".
I tried to add a textMate scope for the "support.function.builtin.python", but is just shows up strikethrought, and isn't applied. Is there a way to have methods such as __init__() come up as one color, but print come up as the colour of normal functions, whatever it is printing
Here is a snippet from the settings.json:
{
                "scope":[
                    "entity.name.function",
                    "support.function.builtin.python"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#97c516",

                },
                
            },
            {
                "scope":[
                    "support.function.magic.python"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#5b7611",

                },
                
            },


Have you tried to add "scope": "support.function.builtin.print.python",?

Yes. Is there a way to specify which scopes take priority over other scopes? Another scope is just overwriting it.

Can i use JSON logical operators, to specify a magic method, that is NOT a builtin.

This should not be feasible at the moment, you can make a feature request in github and vote for it.
